# Calculating the density of the conditional distribution of $Z$ given $X=0$ or $1$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $Z$ be a random variable with continuous distribution having density $f_Z$ which is zero
outside the interval $[0, 1]$

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables, independent given $Z$,
satisfying

$P(X = 1|Z = z) = z = 1−P(X = 0|Z = z) and P(Y = 1|Z = z) = z =1−P(Y = 0|Z = z)$.

a) Calculate the density of the conditional distribution of $Z$ given $X = 0$ and the density of the conditional distribution given $X = 1$.

b) Calculate the conditional probabilities $P(Y = 1|X = 0)$ and $P(Y = 1|X = 1)$

For part a), my idea is to use Bayes Formula but I do not know how to calculate $P(X=0)$ and $P(Z=z)$ as we only have $P(X=1 or 0 |Z=z)$
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use $p$ to denote densities (so e.g. $p(z) = f_Z(z)$).

As you mentioned, by Bayes' theorem we have $$ p(z | x = 0) = \frac{ p(x=0 | z) p(z) }{p(x=0)} = \frac{(1-z)p(z)}{p(x=0)}. $$

One way to compute the constant factor is to note that the left side (and thus, the right side) must be equal to $1$ when integrating over $z\in [0,1].$ This gives $$p(x=0) = \int^1_0 (1-z) p(z) dz = 1 - \mu_Z.$$

A more direct approach is to apply the law of total probability:
$$p(x=0) = \int^1_0 p(x=0, z) dz = \int^1_0 p(x=0|z) p(z) dz = \int^1_0 (1-z) p(z) dz = 1-\mu_Z.$$

Thus, we have the conditional density $$p(z|x=0) = \frac{(1-z)p(z)}{1-\mu_Z}.$$

Through a similar computation, verify for yourself that

$$ p(z|x=1) = \frac{zp(z)}{\mu_Z}.$$

For part b, again we can use Bayes' theorem to start:

$$p(y=1| x=0) = \frac{p(y=1, x=0)}{p(x=0)}.$$
The denominator we have already computed above, $p(x=0) = 1-\mu_Z.$ The numerator needs to be calculated using the law of total probability:

$$ p(y=1, x=0) = \int^1_0 p(y=1, x=0 | z) p(z) dz.$$

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent given $Z,$ we have

$$ p(y=1,x=0) = \int^1_0 z(1-z) p(z) dz = \mu_Z - \mathbb{E}[Z^2]$$ and therefore,

$$ p(y=1|x=0) = \frac{\mu_Z - \mathbb{E}[Z^2]}{1-\mu_Z}.$$

You can compute $p(y=1|x=1)$ in a similar way.

Comment: Appreciate it. The only thing I am unsure of is how $$\int^1_0 z(1-z) p(z) dz = \mu_Z - \mathbb{E}[Z^2]$$

Comment: @MrUsername12 We have $ E[g(Z)] =\int^1_0 g(z) p(z) dz$, so that integral is $E[Z-Z^2].$

Comment: So, when finding $p(y=1,x=1)$, you get the expectation of $Z^2$ so you just get that over $\mu_Z$ for the final answer?

Comment: @MrUsername12 Correct